# How to print One Record Per Page With a Header for each page in PDF document with iTextSharp in C#

Tags: c#, itext, pdf-generation

I am new to iTextSharp.
How can I print one record per page?
Could anyone provide me with some sample code to show me how I can achieve my objective?

Comment: If you are new to iText, why did you choose to use iTextSharp (this is the old name for the C# version of iText 5). Maybe you don't know that iTextSharp has been declared *end of life* in favor of iText 7. From iText 7 on, we no longer talk about iTextSharp; instead we talk about iText 7 for .NET. If you are starting a new project and you still have everything to learn about iText, why would you still use iText 5 when using iText 7 is much more future-proof?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Although people here generally want to help other developers, this is not an outsourcing company. Please provide us with a code-sample of what you have already tried and done.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Solution :

```
using (var output = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var document = new iTextSharp.text.Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4, 40, 40, 30, 90))
                {
                    using (var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, output))
                    {
                        Phrase phrase = null;
                        PdfPCell cell = null;
                        PdfPTable table = null;
                        try
                        {
                            document.Open();
                            document.PageCount = 1;
                            writer.PageEvent = new Footer(data);

                            foreach (var item in data)
                            {
                                table = new PdfPTable(1);
                                table.SpacingBefore = 20;
                                table.WidthPercentage = PageSize.A4.Width;
                                float[] ProfessionalServices = new float[1];
                                ProfessionalServices[0] = (float)(1 * PageSize.A4.Width);
                                table.SetWidthPercentage(ProfessionalServices, PageSize.A4);

                                phrase = new Phrase("Record :" + item);
                                cell = new PdfPCell(phrase);
                                cell.Border = 0;
                                cell.Padding = 2;
                                cell.Colspan = 3;
                                cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
                                table.AddCell(cell);

                                table.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, document.Left, document.Top - (100 + 20), writer.DirectContent);
                                document.Add(table);

                                document.ResetPageCount();
                                document.NewPage();
                            }
                            document.Close();
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {

                        }

                        if (!Directory.Exists(current.Server.MapPath("~/bill-pdf/")))
                            Directory.CreateDirectory(current.Server.MapPath("~/bill-pdf/"));
                        string pdfFilePath = current.Server.MapPath("~/bill-pdf/" + guid + ".pdf");
                        File.WriteAllBytes(pdfFilePath, output.ToArray());
                        if (File.Exists(filePath))
                            File.Delete(filePath);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Footer Method code :

```
#region Footer Class

    public partial class Footer : PdfPageEventHelper
    {
        #region Constructor
        public Footer()
        {

        }
        #endregion

        #region OnStartPage
        public override void OnStartPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
        {
            if (document.PageNumber > 1)
            {
                string footerMessage = "Page " + document.PageNumber;
                Paragraph footer = new Paragraph(footerMessage, FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 9));
                footer.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
                PdfPTable footerTbl = new PdfPTable(numColumns: 1);
                footerTbl.WidthPercentage = 100;
                footerTbl.TotalWidth = PageSize.A4.Width;

                PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(footer));
                cell.Border = 0;
                cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
                footerTbl.AddCell(cell);
                footerTbl.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, document.RightMargin - 80, document.Top + 30, writer.DirectContent);
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region OnEndPage
        public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document doc)
        {

            string footerMessage = "Footer Text";


                Paragraph footer = new Paragraph(footerMessage, FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 9));
                footer.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
                PdfPTable footerTbl = new PdfPTable(numColumns: 1);
                footerTbl.TotalWidth = PageSize.A4.Width;

                PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(footer));
                cell.Border = 0;
                cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
                footerTbl.AddCell(cell);
                //footerTbl.WriteSelectedRows(0, 10, 50, 55, writer.DirectContent);
                footerTbl.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 0, 55, writer.DirectContent);

        }
        #endregion

    }

    #endregion
```

Try code you can set header and footer your own content For header modify `OnStartPage()` and for footer modify `OnEndPage()`

Comment: @Bruno Lowagie yes, I don't know why people just downvoted immediately

Comment: Maybe because it is a code-only answer? There are some topics on meta about code-only answers, so apparently it is a Thing on SO.

Comment: Thanks all of you for the solution. I was kind of busy over the last of couple of days. I would try the solution and let you know if I face some issues.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. Recommended solution is working with a little tweak.